# MySQL - Putting an entire tables's records into another table with a unique ID column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy the entire contents of one table (bids_accepted) and archive it by placing all the rows in the table into the archive_bids_accepted table.  The tables are exactly the same except the archive_bids_accepted table has 1 extra column (first column) to give the entire set of bids a uniqueID (created in the step before).

What's the right MySQL syntax to do this?  I think it's close, but can't get the syntax just right.

```
// gets the unique ID
long id = DBUtil.executeInsert("INSERT INTO archive (create_username,create_ts,update_username,update_ts) VALUES('', NOW(),'',NOW())");

// MySQL syntax causing problems
String sql = "INSERT INTO archive_bids_accepted VALUES(" + id + ",select * from bids_accepted)";

// Also tried this
String sql = "INSERT INTO archive_bids_accepted " + id + ",select b.* from bids_accepted b";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to manually insert a value for `id`. Just let MySQL do it for you by using `AUTOINCREMENT`:

```
CREATE TABLE archive
(
  Id int AUTOINCREMENT,
  create_username <datatype>,
  create_ts <datatype>,
  update_username <datatype>,
  update_ts <datatype>
)
```

Then execute the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO archive_bids_accepted 
  (create_username, create_ts, update_username, update_ts)
SELECT create_username, create_ts, update_username, update_ts 
FROM bids_accepted
```

The `Id` field will be filled automatically.

Comment: It gives an error saying the column count doesn't match.  Here's how I set up the archive_id field in the archive_bids_accepted table.


auction_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: If the column count doesn't match, try specifying the columns to select. I've updated my answer above accordingly.